send compressed message with boto3 to SQS
Is there a way to send a compressed message to SQS with boto3? I don't find examples. Thanks, Stella
I tried to give bytes to send_message, get error
client = boto3.client(service, region_name="us-east-1")
msg_body=b'bytes_message'
client.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MessageBody=msg_body,
    DelaySeconds=delay
    )

your text`Invalid type for parameter MessageBody, value:type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>


convert bytes to string
in the second line of your code add this and try
  msg_body = str(b'bytes_message',utf-8')

